# How to store links inside JS and open it via html dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Sorry, I am completely new to all of this...

I am trying to create a music library for my own music. I have all of the song data in "songs" and I can load multiple tracks with audio, image, description name etc. What I can't work out is how to get a button to load for each track which will open a link from each of the "songs" (license_url) -

This is what I've got in the div.
< button class="button_2" @click='window.location.href = "song.license_url"'>License.....

Below is the html, js files. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```js
    songs: [



      {
        id: 7,
        title: "Song 1",
        artist: "Apex Music PRS",
        description: "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description ",
        url:
          "./mp3/song1.mp3",
        cover_art_url:
          "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/november.jpg",
        license_url: "https://google.com"
      },

      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Song 2",
        artist: "Apex Music PRS",
        description: "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description ",
        url:
          "./mp3/song2.mp3",
        cover_art_url:
          "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/november.jpg",
        license_url: "https://gumroad.com"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Song 3",
        artist: "Apex Music PRS",
        description: "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description ",
        url:
          "./mp3/song3.mp3",
        cover_art_url:
          "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/november.jpg",
        license_url: "https://facebook.com"
      },

      {
        id: 6,
        title: "song 4",
        artist: "Apex Music PRS",
        description: "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description ",
        url:
          "./mp3/song4.mp3",
        cover_art_url:
          "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/november.jpg",
        license_url: "https://twitter.com"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: "song5",
        artist: "Apex Music PRS",
        description: "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description ",
        url:
          "./mp3/song5.mp3",
        cover_art_url:
          "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/november.jpg",
        license_url: "https://google.com"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "song 6",
        artist: "Apex Music PRS",
        description: "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description ",
        url:
          "./mp3/song6.mp3",
        cover_art_url:
          "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/november.jpg",
        license_url: "https://google.com"
      },

      {
        id: 4,
        title: "song 7",
        artist: "Apex Music PRS",
        description: "Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description ",
        url:
          "./mp3/song7.mp3",
        cover_art_url:
          "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/november.jpg",
        license_url: "https://google.com"
      },


    ],
```

```html
  <div id="app">

  <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>

      <template v-for='song in songs'>
         <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 song" >

           <div class='wrapper'>


            <div class="overlay-play text-center" v-if="isPlaying && (currentSong.id === song.id )" @click='pause'>
               <i class="icon ion-ios-pause"></i>
           </div>

            <div class="overlay-play text-center" @click='play(song)'v-else>

              <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>


           </div>

              <img :src="song.cover_art_url" alt="" class='img-fluid rounded'>


           </div>

           <button class="button_2" @click='window.location.href = "song.license_url"'>License</button>
           <h1 class='song-title mt-2'>{{song.title}}</h1>
           <p class='song-artiste' >{{song.artist}}</p>
           <p class="song-description" >{{song.description}}</p>


         </div>

       </template>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Would you please pare down your code to provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that *just* illustrates the issue you're having? You've said you are able to load/store images, audio, text... but not a hyperlink? Why not? Is there an error? Are you having issues dynamically generating the html for the hyperlink? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have edited it to hopefully be more clear. I think I need a script to get the button link to follow the url from "license_url" for example  the "License" button on song one will take the user to Google, but the same button on song 2 will take the user to Gumroad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddel Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6mc4szv7/)

You Just need to add to your `<button>` a click event and pass through it the `song.license_url` that you rendered from the `v-for` loop...like this

`<button class="button_2" @click='openLicense(song.license_url)'>License</button>`

and in your `<script>`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{//your data is here
  },
  methods:{
   //Pass the songs license url value 
    openLicense(e){
      //will open the url into a new tab  
      window.open(e)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use a normal anchor-element instead of a button.
So just replace `button` with `<a href={{song.song.license_url}}/>` and it should work.